# cypher query composite relationship match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

with a graph successfully matching

```
MATCH (a:A)-[x:X]-(b:B)-[y:Y]-(c:C) RETURN *
```

is it possible to return something like

```
(a:A)-[z:Z]-(c:C)
```

which has a 'new' relationship z (let's call it 'linked via a B') that does not exist in the graph database, and that in effect represents a collapsing of

```
-[x:X]-(b:B)-[y:Y]-
```

to

```
-[z:Z]-
```

Note, that the relationship `-[z:Z]-` does not exist in the graph.

Possible? What would the cypher look like?

thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen to all the properties that may be in `x`, `y`, and `z` when you "collapse" them? And what if some properties have the same name?

Comment: by collapse i simply mean don't want part of a returned query, with a virtual relationship returned in their place. InverseFalcon below has sorted me. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with [virtual relationships](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_virtual_nodes_rels) via [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/):

```
MATCH (a:A)-[x:X]-(b:B)-[y:Y]-(c:C)
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(a,'Z',{}, c) YIELD rel
RETURN a, rel, c
```